# Need to download a set of unique numbers from a server for use locally

Tags: mysql, vba, uniqueidentifier

MSAccess program deployed to 100 users who my not have internet access while using the program.  So they need to store the information locally until they have an internet connect, then upload to the server.  The issue is that MSAccess assigns a unique number for a new parent record.  It then uses this unique number for child tables.
When the local tables are uploaded, there is the possibility of duplicate ParentIDs. I understand that I can have the MYSQL database create another unique number that would be unique to all parent records, but the Child records (From different uploads) would still have duplicate IDs.
I'm trying to figure out how to download a set of unique IDs from the server and store them locally.  Then when a parent record is created, it is assigned one of the downloaded IDs instead of an auto incremented number.  This way all the child records would have a Parent ID unique to one parent record.
I'm nhaving trouble figuring out how to store these numbers locally and the process to assign them locally.
Any Ideas.
Adolph

Comment: How do you merge the MA Access data into your MySQL database?

Comment: Starting with the access program, I use "BullZip MSAccess to MySql" program to convert the tables into a sql statement.  I then import/run the sql statement in the MySql database.  Most of the data types convert with no issues.  I then use an ODBC connector to upload/download data between the two systems.